# Help with regular expression

Tags: regex

Trying to build a regular expression that will match all strings that begin with word "med-" and end with ".opol.nei.com" like this one

```
med-fe3-ua-kiol-33.opol.nei.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perl, sed, grep:

```
med-.*.opol.nei.com
```

bash expansion:

```
med-*.opol.nei.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Wayne Yux answer might match more than what is intended. `med-.*.opol.nei.com` will match any character instead of the dots.

For example: `med-abcXopolYneiZcom` will match the regex above.

To be more specific the dots should be escaped like this: `med-.*\.opol\.nei\.com`. Here the dot is interpreted as a dot only.

Comment: add a `$` at the end of the regex, it match something like `med-ecbv.opol.nei.comTEST` if not (using `grep "med-.*\.opol\.nei\.com$"` command)

Comment: also, there is the `^` for matching the begenning, it match Amed-ecbv.opol.nei.com if not ( using `grep "^med-.*\.opol\.nei\.com$"` command)